# Is bordercolor with tables cross client friendly in emails?

Tags: html, html-table, border, html-email

I want to change the border color of a table within my HTML email to another color but when I run my code through the HTML Validation it doesn't seem to like (bordercolor="#9cbdcc")

I've added an image below so you can see the error I get.

The main reason I'm asking this is that I'm now sending a lot of HTML emails to a lot of people and generally go for 100% validation to ensure there are minimal problems across all the email clients so it would be handy to know is this is a no no or if its okay.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

[image]

Decided to us the method below, the ticked answer would also work:

HTML

```
 <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#000000">
 <tr>
 <td width="200" height="30" bgcolor="#FF0000">
     TEST
     </td>
     <td width="200" height="30" bgcolor="#FF0000">
     TEST
     </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Emails are notoriously difficult to get to display properly across all clients. Generally styles are done (mostly) inline. Try styling the border color with inline CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I always use inline styles as a general practice for my emails, the problem I have with the inline CSS below is that it doesn't apply the border to the cells, only to the outside of the table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about using inline styles or a stylesheet?

```
<table style="border-color:#9cbdcc;">
```

or

```
<table style="border: 1px solid #9cbdcc;">
```

They work perfectly in emails in all the clients.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I need all the cells within the table to also have the border and the above only aplies a border to the table not the cells.

Comment: @huddds Okay, You would need to add the style attribute to all your elements.

Comment: I've just thought of a really easy way to get what I'm after, I'll add it to my question, but yours would work if you dont mind doubling up on the edges when a 1px meets a 1px

Comment: @hudds Yep. Would take some ingenuity for sure.

Answer (score 1):

@hudds accepted answer is the way to go, also if you are looking to add border to all cells evenly, then you can add border attribute to the table like so `<table border="10" bordercolor="black">` This should add border to table cells